# Activity design missing elements in preview

Tags: android, android-studio

My app is different when running to when editing in the design tab. Any reason why this is? An example is the Options in the ActionBar not showing. Here's the activity:

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fafafa">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

home_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dark_theme"
        android:title="@string/dark_theme" />

</menu>
```

home.java

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here the Options menu in the ActionBar doesn't show (everything else shows fine). When I run the app the Options menu comes up fine. Any idea why?

Comment: What about your R.menu.home_menu ? Have you defined items in it ?

Comment: Use this in item
android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: or app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: This? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a Options menu through Overriding onCreateOptionsMenu not through XML design, thats why its not showing in preview..if you what to remove Options menu just remove that Overriding method